# to split a String from an XML file

Tags: java, xml

i'm reading an xml file which contain the attributes of many objects of a Class; I'm using a DOM xml parser; in this Class there is also an array field (NEARBOXID), so I would know if is a good way to read it from the xml file like a single String and then split its content, or is there any better way to do this?

the file is like this:

```
<CONFIGURATION>
<CONFIG> 
    <BOXID>1</BOXID> 
    <LENGTH>100</LENGTH>
    <NEARBOXID>2,3,4,5</NEARBOXID>
</CONFIG>
    <CONFIG> 
    <BOXID>2</BOXID> 
    <LENGTH>200</LENGTH>
    <NEARBOXID>1,8</NEARBOXID>
</CONFIG>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read as string and split it. Using a loop convert the numbers into integer using `ParseInt`

Comment: ok, thankyou! this is the first way i use xml, so i want to write the best code I can

Answer (score 1):

No, it's up to you to split that field. The [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method will do it just fine.

Comment: ok, thankyou! this is the first way i use xml, so i want to write the best code I can

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the complete data within the required tag using [XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html), and later use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), to get the desired values out of the complete string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are converting your XML to Java objects, I will demonstrate how this could be done using a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation.  A JAXB implementation is included in the JDK/JRE starting with Java SE 6.

I would recommend changing the contents of the `NEARBOXID` element to be space separated.

```
<NEARBOXID>2 3 4 5</NEARBOXID>
```

The corresponds to the following entry in an XML schema.  This means that you could validate that the element contains space separated int values instead of space separated Strings.

```
  <xs:element name="NEARBOXID" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:list itemType="xs:int"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

**Config**

Then you could map the element using JAXB's `@XmlList` annotation (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Config {

    @XmlElement(name="BOXID")
    private int boxId;

    @XmlElement(name="LENGTH")
    private int length;

    @XmlElement(name="NEARBOXID")
    @XmlList
    private int[] nearBoxIds;

}
```

**Configuration**

The object below would map to the root of your XML document.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="CONFIGURATION")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Configuration {

    @XmlElement(name="CONFIG")
    private List<Config> configs;

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code to prove that everything works.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14305301/input.xml");
        Configuration configuration = (Configuration) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(configuration, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

Below is the input to and output from running the demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CONFIGURATION>
    <CONFIG>
        <BOXID>1</BOXID>
        <LENGTH>100</LENGTH>
        <NEARBOXID>2 3 4 5</NEARBOXID>
    </CONFIG>
    <CONFIG>
        <BOXID>2</BOXID>
        <LENGTH>200</LENGTH>
        <NEARBOXID>1 8</NEARBOXID>
    </CONFIG>
</CONFIGURATION>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a matter of choice. You can use it that way as:

```
<NEARBOXID>2,3,4,5</NEARBOXID>
```

or you use it that way:

```
<NEARBOXID>2</NEARBOXID>
<NEARBOXID>3</NEARBOXID>
<NEARBOXID>4</NEARBOXID>
<NEARBOXID>5</NEARBOXID>
```

Second way requires you to have different parsing code than the first one, but you can save some code on splitting and dealing with string.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the data as a String and perform split() on it.

Better approach for it is to maintain in individual tags like

```
<NEARBOXID>2</NEARBOXID>
<NEARBOXID>3</NEARBOXID>
<NEARBOXID>4</NEARBOXID>
<NEARBOXID>5</NEARBOXID>
```

For parsing the xml query you can use XPath, XQuery or JAXB depending on your requirement.

Comment: With JAXB you could also handle space separated values using the `@XmlList` annotation:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14306692/383861